# Rescaling image causes loss of pixels

Tags: c#, winforms

I seem to be having trouble up-scaling an image that is 8x8 pixels. When testing, I wanted to scale the image up to 64x64 pixels. However, when doing so, this was the result:

[image: Result of scale]

Rescaling it the way I did below, removes 4 pixels height on the top, and 4 pixels width on the left, and adds 4 black pixels height on the bottom, and 4 pixels width on the right.

Here is the code I am using to rescale the image:

```
private static Image ScaleImage(string username, int size)
{
    Image avatar = MergeImage(username);

    int originalWidth = avatar.Width;
    int originalHeight = avatar.Height;

    float ratioX = (float)size / (float)originalWidth;
    float ratioY = (float)size / (float)originalHeight;
    float ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

    int newWidth = (int)(originalWidth * ratio);
    int newHeight = (int)(originalHeight * ratio);

    Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb);

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
    {
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
        g.DrawImage(avatar, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    }

    return newImage;
}
```

I am unsure of what is going wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm far from an expert, but have you tried `PixelFormat.Format64bppRgb` ?

Comment: What does the original image look like? And what exactly did you expect to happen? You're trying to turn 64 pixels into 4,096 pixels. Blowing an image up by that much is definitely going to make for a very blocky result.

Comment: @FizzBuzz PixelFormat does not contain a definition for Format64bppRgb

Comment: @JimMischel That's the point, the goal is a blocky result, because the original is blocky to begin with. That's why I'm using "InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor" which reserves the hard edges. Think of the original image as pixel art. the best way to upscale it is by reserving hard edges, so that it will look the same so long that it is scaled by factors of 8.

Also, I'm not trying to turn 64 pixels in to 4096 pixels. I don't even know where you got that. I'm trying to upscale an image that is 8 x 8 pixels to an image that is 64 x 64 pixels.

Comment: 8x8 pixels is 64 pixels. 64 x 64 pixels is 4,096 pixels. Show the original image. Without it, it's impossible to say if the result you show is correct behavior.

Comment: @JimMischel I think you're mistaking the dimensions for multiplication. I am not saying "64 x 64" as in "64 TIMES 64". I am saying it as a dimension. As in the left value is width, and the right value is height. I don't see how you got multiplication out of that. Maybe instead of "64 x 64", I should have said, "64 by 64"? Would that have made it more easy for you to understand?

Comment: I know you've solved it already, I'm just curious as to how PixelFormat doesn't contain the 64 bit definition. I checked before posting and it's definitely there...Are you running/target the latest .NET framework? (Definition: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If an image is 8 pixels in width and 8 pixels in height, then there are 64 total pixels in the image, yes? If the image is 64 pixels wide and 64 pixels in height, there is a total of 4,096 pixels in the image. If this isn't the case in your image, then you're using some rather non-standard terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this before `g.DrawImage`:

```
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
```